# Serving a prototype page in Wakanda 2.4+

Tags: wakanda

Currently using Wakanda 1.1.3 with a mostly Angular4 on client side, yet, a few prototype pages persist from
our initial project. Provided we make the necessary file structure, module, login and syntax changes for v2,
will Wakanda v2.4+ serve our older prototype pages?

If so, is there anything special or unique that we need to do to get a prototype page to load?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the WAF files (JS & CSS) generated by the v1.1.3 runtime for each prototype page.

- Open your prototype page in a browser.
- Open the browser console.
- Save both `waf~css` and `waf~js` files.
- Hard link these files in your prototype page.

This should be enough to run on Wakanda v.2.6.0